# Ist der Gebrauch von "bevor nicht" korrekt?

Tags: word-usage

Hier ist eine Frage, die mich schon länger umtreibt. Es geht um die Konstruktion "bevor nicht".

Betrachten wir folgendes Beispiel aus der Neuen Zürcher Zeitung vom 10.12.2010:

> Die Dossiers können jedoch nicht verabschiedet werden, bevor nicht die Kernfrage beim Treibhausgasausstoss gelöst ist.
>   ([Quelle](https://www.nzz.ch/klimawandel_schweizer_delegation_cancun-1.8623999))

Ich stosse mich an dem Wort "nicht" nach dem Wort "bevor". Meiner Meinung nach müsste das Wort "nicht" weggelassen werden, alternativ könnte man auch "bevor" durch "solange" ersetzen. Wie sehen Sie das?

Comment: Müsste es weggelassen werden, oder muss es weggelassen werden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

»Bevor nicht« hat man als Muttersprachler eindeutig im Ohr, andererseits macht dessen Verwendung im genannten Beispiel einen falschen Eindruck. Wie kann das sein?

Der Duden klärt auf.

> Die Konjunktion »bevor« drückt aus, dass etwas noch nicht ist oder
>   geschieht, wenn ein anderes Geschehen bereits eintritt: *Ich kam nach
>   Hause, bevor Vater da war* (d. h., Vater war noch nicht da, als ich
>   nach Hause kam). Die Konjunktion »bevor« enthält also schon eine
>   negative Aussage **und es ist deshalb nicht korrekt, wenn man nach einem
>   verneinten Hauptsatz auch den »bevor«-Satz zusätzlich verneint.** Also
>   nicht: *Mutter legt sich nie zu Bett, bevor Vater nicht da ist*,
>   sondern: *..., bevor Vater da ist*. Also nicht: *Ich treffe keine
>   Entscheidung, bevor ich mit ihm nicht gesprochen habe*, sondern: ...*,
>   bevor ich mit ihm gesprochen habe*. **Wenn der Nebensatz dem Hauptsatz vorangeht (und außer der zeitlichen Aussage auch eine Bedingung zum Ausdruck gebracht wird), wird dagegen die Negation gesetzt:** *Bevor du nicht unterschrieben hast, lasse ich dich nicht fort.*
>   <sub>Quelle: Duden, Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 1998</sub>

Die gleiche Beurteilung findet sich in [diesem Germanistik-Lehrbuch](https://books.google.de/books?id=91XeDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=Die%20Konjunktion%20%C2%BBbevor%C2%AB%20dr%C3%BCckt%20aus,%20dass%20etwas%20noch%20nicht%20ist%20oder%20geschieht,%20wenn%20ein%20anderes%20Geschehen%20bereits%20eintritt:&source=bl&ots=igqA4ZUcpC&sig=d5ja5bpLJFJ9sJyDbEa-DwSnEfA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHoc3tnYrZAhXOyKQKHSyoAO8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Die%20Konjunktion%20%C2%BBbevor%C2%AB%20dr%C3%BCckt%20aus%2C%20dass%20etwas%20noch%20nicht%20ist%20oder%20geschieht%2C%20wenn%20ein%20anderes%20Geschehen%20bereits%20eintritt%3A&f=false).

Answer (score 6):

Sowohl [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bevor) als auch [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bevor) führen genau diese Verwendung von *bevor nicht* auf.

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bevor) schreibt dazu

> leitet einen Bedingungssatz ein, in dem die temporale Bedeutung der Konjunktion zurücktritt; steht vor, **auch nach** verneintem Hauptsatz

und führen unter anderen folgende Beispiele auf

> - bevor nicht der letzte Mann aus dem Stollen geborgen ist, gehen wir nicht von der Unglücksstelle
> - bevor die Schulaufgaben nicht fertig sind, dürft ihr nicht spielen
> - Sie darf nicht fernsehen, bevor nicht ihre Hausaufgaben gemacht sind

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese Beispiele! Eigentlich streng logisch gesehen sind die inkorrekt oder? (Was spricht gegen: "Sie darf nicht fernsehen, bevor ihre Hausaufgaben gemacht sind"?)

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen: die Beispiele stammen von Duden und DWDS, die verschiedene Quellen nach der Verwendung deutscher Sprache durchforsten. Sprache ist nicht immer (selten ?) logisch. Es ist nicht falsch zu sagen: *Sie darf nicht fernsehen, bevor ihre Hausaufgaben gemacht sind*, es geht hier beides. Manchmal ist es nur eine Frage der Häufigkeit.

Comment: da macht es sich der Duden ganz schön einfach. Logik kann man nicht so drehen, wie es einem passt. Ich bin Franzose und bei mir sträubt sich hier alles... Bevor nicht beinhaltet eine Zeitgrenze, solange eine Dauer, das sind zwei Paar Schuh...

Answer (score 4):

Das `nicht` sollte im Kontext erhalten bleiben - es ist hier allerdings sprachlich etwas erschwerend platziert und folgt schnell auf ein erstes `nicht`. Hier sind eventuell auch Einflüsse aus dem Schweizer Sprachraum gegeben. Meine Vorschläge:

> Die Dossiers können jedoch nicht verabschiedet werden, solange die Kernfrage beim Treibhausgasausstoss nicht gelöst ist.

oder

> Die Dossiers können jedoch erst verabschiedet werden, nachdem die Kernfrage beim Treibhausgasausstoss gelöst ist.

Answer (score 3):

Entweder ist das *nicht* zu viel - bevor drückt Vorzeitigkeit vor einem Zeitpunkt oder Ereignis aus - oder es muss *solange nicht* heißen. *Bevor nicht* ist mindestens logisch falsch.

Comment: *Bevor* hat eine eigene Bedeutung in verneinten Nebensätzen, die in ebenfalls verneinte Hauptsätze eingebettet sind und heißt dann einfach "solange". https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bevor#Bedeutung2